# Unable to swap plans during trial with Laravel Cashier Paddle

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-cashier, paddle-paddle

According to Cashier [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cashier-paddle#changing-plans), you should be able to swap Paddle plans while being on trial, moreover trial itself should be maintained:

> To update the subscription plan for a user, you should pass the Paddle plan's identifier to the subscription's `swap` method (...) **If the user is on a trial, the trial period will be maintained.**

However, when I'm using `swap` method:

`$user->subscription('default')->swap($planId);`

I'm getting an error: **LogicException: Cannot swap plans while on trial.**
*([\vendor\laravel\cashier-paddle\src\Subscription.php:767](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-paddle/blob/4137c72188cbcd7f2b35ebf1bcfff5e3be26f137/src/Subscription.php#L767))*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an error in documentation itself because [Paddle API](https://developer.paddle.com/api-reference/subscription-api/users/updateuser#usage-notes) does not offer swapping subscription during trial.

> Subscribers cannot be moved to a different plan while on a trialing state.

[GutHub issue](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-paddle/issues/145)'s closed.